# How to automatically close media when switching to another class in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an Android app. I created a class for the media menu. When I return from the media menu to the main activity, the sound works, but if I return to the media menu again, the sound does not cut off. Moreover, if I then press the pause button, the application crashes!

How can I solve this issue? I have thought of a lot of solutions except that I cannot create a destroy function because it is not present in the options.

Here is my code:

```java
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mdp == null) {
            mdp = MediaPlayer.create(context, d.getsound());
            mdp.start();
        } else {
            mdp.pause();
            mdp = MediaPlayer.create(context, d.getsound());
            mdp.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot my friend

```
@Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mdp.stop();
        mdp.release();

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this idea is known to me, but the onPause function does not work because it is a subclass not activity, so I need the life cycle of the class and its functions because when setting this function it gives me an error that the function is not recognized